# Getting leaflet marker information from a click event

Tags: c#, leaflet

I have multiple of the following markers on my leaflet map. I wish that when I click on the marker that I can get the name that I set for the marker in "customValue". How do I do this? I understand that the e in "changeMapLineColour(e) " is for the event, how to I get marker information out?

Thank you very much :)

```
var volMarker;
var volMarkers = new Array();
function drawMapLabel(line, name) {

     volMarker = new L.marker([line.start.lat, line.start.lng], {
        draggable: true,
        autoPan: true,
        customValue: name
    }).bindTooltip(name,
        {
            permanent: true,
            direction: 'right'
        }).addTo(mymap).on('click', changeMapLineColour); 

    volMarkers.push(volMarker);
    return volMarker;
}

function changeMapLineColour(e) {        
    alert("hi. you clicked the marker at " NAMEHERE);
}
```

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#event-target

Comment: thanks for that. I understand I have to use the target call but how do I get the customValue from the marker? Everything I try comes out as undefined... var name = $(e.target).attr('customValue'); e.target.customValue; Sorry, I am very new to this. Thanks

Comment: That should be in `.target.options.customValue` IIRC.

Comment: Do not mix jQuery everywhere. Think JavaScript rather than DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the above from Ivan. In a marker you can create your own custom values, below I have created 2: nameValue and userSelectedColour.

```
         vMarker = new L.marker([line.start.lat, line.start.lng], {
            draggable: true,
            autoPan: true,
            nameValue: name,
            userSelectedColour: selectedColour
        }).bindTooltip(name,
            {
                permanent: true,
                direction: 'right'
            }).addTo(mymap).on('click', changeMapLineColour);
```

Then to access the values use:

```
function changeMapLineColour(e) {
//some stuff then:
lines[i].setStyle({
                    color: e.target.options.userSelectedColour,
                    weight: 3


                   })
}
```